# Finding roots of given quadratic without discriminant

Tags: polynomials, roots, quadratics

I've been trying to factorize this quadratic equation to find it's roots. (I know how to use discriminant but this has to be solved using factorization)[image]

I asssumed the middle term will split in terms of √5 and then I'm stuck at another quadratic. Can't figure out it's roots without using discriminant.
Any help?

Comment: It seems your thinking on this was confused from the very first line of the attempted solution. You say $\text{sum} = -\sqrt5 x$, but when you write "sum", what is it a sum of? And why does it equal $-\sqrt5x$ (rather than some other total such as $\sqrt5$)? What do $a$ and $b$ have to do with the sum, or with the original equation, or with anything? Perhaps if you write your ideas in a more definite form, saying exactly what each thing means and exactly what is the reason for each step, you will spend time initially to write this but you will save a lot of time not doing wrong things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the *quadratic complement*, that is,
divide the equation by the coefficient of $x^2$, then add and subtract the square of half of the new coefficient of $x$.

So let us firstly divide the given equation by $2$, yielding
$$x^2-\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}x-1=0.$$
Then we add and subtract $5/16$ to the left member:
$$x^2-\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}x+\frac{5}{16}-\frac{5}{16}-1=0.$$
Tidying up gives
$$\Big(x-\frac{\sqrt 5}{4}\Big)^2=\frac{21}{16}.$$
Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 1):

It is all a matter of presentation I suppose. Here is one approach:

The roots solve $x^2-\frac{\sqrt 5 }{2} x-1=0$. The vertex is at $\sqrt 5/4,$ and since the roots are equidistant  (call it a distance $t$) from the vertex and multiply to $-1$, we have
$(\sqrt 5/4-t)(\sqrt 5/4+t)=-1\implies 5/16-t^2=-1\implies t=\sqrt {21}/4,$

implying the roots are $\frac{\sqrt 5\pm\sqrt{21}}{4}$.